# Como fazer select MySQL utilizando input tipo date com php?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando listar determinadas colunas do banco de dados pela data mas não funciona.

[image]

Segue trecho do código:

```
<?php
if($_GET['busca'] == "data") {        
  $datai = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['data']));
  $nome  = $_POST['nome'];
  $preco = $_POST['preco'];
  $qtd   = $_POST['qtd'];

  $query = mysqli_query("SELECT data, nome, preco, SUM(preco) AS pr, SUM(qtd) AS qtd, date_format(data, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data FROM tbl_carrinho WHERE idGarcon='$garcon' AND data BETWEEN '$datai' AND '$dataf' AND time BETWEEN '$hora1' AND '$hora2' GROUP BY data") or die(mysqli_error());
}

while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {    
  $data = $resultado['data'];    
  $nome = $resultado['nome'];    
  $qtd = $resultado['qtd'];    
  $preco = $resultado['preco'];
?>

<tr style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;">    
  <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $data ?></td>
  <td align="left" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $nome ?></td>
  <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $preco ?></td>
  <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $qtd ?></td>
</tr>
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Bom, se caso a coluna de data da sua tabela mysql esteja no formato correto tipo (date=Y-m-d), eu converteria a data de acordo com a tabela mysql.

EX:

Se você tem os dados armazenados cujo as datas estejam dessa forma '2017-08-15', o ideal é que você converta sua variável:

```
$datai = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['data']));
```

para

```
$datai = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['data']));
```

A mesma coisa eu faria com a variável $dataf e na instrução mysql eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
"SELECT data, nome, preco, SUM(preco) AS pr, SUM(qtd) AS qtd, data FROM tbl_carrinho WHERE idGarcon='$garcon' AND data BETWEEN ".$datai." AND ".$dataf." AND time BETWEEN ".$hora1." AND ".$hora2." GROUP BY data"
```

Procure não colocar suas variáveis utilizando aspas simples dentro de aspas duplas, pois o php pode interpretar isso como uma string e não como uma variável.
EX.

Problema:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col='$val'";
```

Solução alternativa

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=".$val."";
```

ou

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = {$val}";
```

Espero ter ajudado.

abs.

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro, você só está passando uma data, se quer filtrar por um período entre duas datas é melhor passar as duas datas (logicamente) e caso ele digite só uma ele pegue os registros somente dessa data.

Primeiro crie os campos para data inicial e data final no formulário.

Veja se o método do seu form é POST ou GET e altere o código.

O código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['dataIni']) && (isset($_POST['dataFin']))) {        
  $dataIni = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['dataIni']));
  $dataFin = date('Y/m/d', strtotime($_POST['dataFin']));
  $nome  = $_POST['nome'];
  $preco = $_POST['preco'];
  $qtd   = $_POST['qtd'];

  $sql = "SELECT data, nome, preco, SUM(preco) AS pr, SUM(qtd) AS qtd, date_format(data, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data FROM tbl_carrinho WHERE idGarcon='$garcon' AND data ";

  if ($dataFin != '') {
    $sql .= "BETWEEN '$dataIni' AND '$dataFin' GROUP BY data"
  else
    $sql .= "= '$dataIni' GROUP BY data"

  $query = mysqli_query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

  while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {    
?>    
<tr style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;">    
  <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $resultado['data'] ?></td>
  <td align="left" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $resultado['nome'] ?></td>
  <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $resultado['preco'] ?></td>
  <td align="center" style="border:1px solid #f2f2f2;"><?php echo $qtd ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } } else { echo 'Informe o período!'} ?>
```

Não tive tempo de testar.

Answer (score -1):

Aparentemente, você não está utilizando corretamente a linguagem SQL.

A instrução GROUP BY geralmente é usada com funções agregadas (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) para agrupar o conjunto de resultados por uma ou mais colunas.

> Exemplo do uso: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby

O melhor a ser usado seria ORDER BY

A instrução ORDER BY é usada para classificar o conjunto de resultados em ordem ascendente ou decrescente.

> Exemplo do uso: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_orderby

ficaria dessa forma a linha do código já alterada:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT data, nome, preco, SUM(preco) AS pr, SUM(qtd) AS qtd, date_format(data, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data FROM tbl_carrinho WHERE idGarcon='$garcon' AND data BETWEEN '$datai' AND '$dataf' AND time BETWEEN '$hora1' AND '$hora2' ORDER BY data") or die(mysqli_error());
```

// foi utilizado order by ao invés de group by